# Insert more rows at a time using bcp

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert, bcp

User is using the `bcp` command to load data from a Linux command prompt.

As of now it is loading 1000 rows at a time. There are 9970001000 total rows to send to SQL Server.

If he wants to insert more than 1000 at a time, what do we need to do or enable on the SQL Server end?

Answer (score 4):

BCP is a command line utility with switches that are used to control the import process, including the number of rows per batch.  The number of rows is not as important as the number of rows per second that are being imported.

BCP documentation and examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms162802.aspx

The switch to control the batch size is:
**-b batch_size**

The speed of the import is affected by variables including the target table (indexes, heap vs clustered, etc.), the I/O capacity of the server, how busy the server is, the type of logging that is enabled, speed of the network, speed of the process on the client machine, etc.

I suggest you first start looking at the target table and go from there.